# ¿Cómo diseñar un menú en Python?

Tags: python

Mis amigos y otro empezamos a explorar Python, y uno de los problemas con los que nos topamos de cómo diseña un menú es el siguiente:

Diseñar un menú con las siguientes 4 funciones:

1. Leer un número de 4 dígitos, mostrar el dígito mayor e informar si es par o impar.
2. Leer dos números de 3 dígitos cada uno, formar un tercer número con el mayor del primero y el menor del segundo.
3. Leer un número de 3 dígitos y formar el mayor número posible con sus cifras.
4. Salir

Agradezco su ayuda :D

Comment: Cuál es el problema?

Comment: el problema lo tenemos al diseñar un menú con las características descritas en el enunciado. Lo que pasa es que somos principiantes en programación (sobre todo yo jeje). Y pues, supongo que podemos aprender de esta comunidad :D

Comment: para diseñar un menu utiliza un bucle while, condicionales if, elif y por ultimo prints para imprimir por pantalla las opciones si es eso a lo que te refieres.

Comment: Deberías mostrar algo que ya hayas hecho, puesto que no se refleja una investigación o esfuerzo empleado en solucionar dicho problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero define tus funciones:

#### Función 1

```
def funcion1():
    num = input("Ingresa un numero de 4 cifras: ")  #Recibes el numero
    num = list(num) #Crea una lista donde cada elemento corresponde a un numero
    maxNum = int(max(num)) #Obtienes el valor mas alto
    if maxNum%2 == 0: #Evaluamos si el residuo entre 2 es 0 
        print("Numero: ", maxNum, '- Es par') #Muestra
    else:
        print("Numero: ", maxNum, '- No es par') #Muestra
```

#### Función 2

```
def funcion2():
    num = input("Ingresa 2 numeror de 3 digitos: ")  #Recibes los numeros
    num = num.split() #Hacemos una lista con dos elementos (los numeros)
    maxNum = max(list(num[0])) #Obtenemos el mayor digito del primer numeor
    minNum = min(list(num[1])) #Obtenemos el menor digito del segundo numeor
    nuevoNumero = int(maxNum+minNum)  #Concatena y convierte a int
    print('Numero formado: ', nuevoNumero) # Muestra
```

#### Función 3

```
def funcion3():
    num = input("Ingresa un numero de 3 cifras: ")  #Recibes el numero
    num = list(num) #Crea una lista donde cada elemento corresponde a un numero
    numeroList = list() #Crea una lista vacia
    for i in range(3):  #Ciclo for que por cada numero elige el mayor y lo agrega a numeroList
        mayor = num.index(max(num))
        numeroList.append(num[mayor])
        num.pop(mayor)
    nuevoNumero = int(numeroList[0]+ numeroList[1]+ numeroList[2]) #Concatena y convierte a int
    print('Numero formado: ', nuevoNumero) # Muestra
```

Una vez definidas todas solo crea el menu

#### Menu

```
op=1
while op != 4: #Se ejecuta mientras op sea diferente de 4
    print('1.funcion1\n2.funcion2\n3.funcion3\n4.Salir') #Muestra las opciones
    op = int(input('Ingresa una opcion: ')) # Usuario ingresa opcion
    
    if op == 1:
        funcion1()
    elif op == 2:
        funcion2()
    elif op == 3:
        funcion3()
    elif op == 4:
        print('Salio...')
    else:
        print('Ingrese una opcion valida')
```

Puedes agregar que antes de volver al menu el programa se quede en pausa hasta que el usuario presione alguna tecla y que tambien se borre la consola antes de regresar al menu, pero eso te lo dejo de tarea.

Comment: Hacerle los deberes a los demás no está demasiado bien visto por aquí. Te recomiendo que evites responder a preguntas cuyo único contenido es el enunciado de la tarea que les ha sido asignada y en vez de eso les invites a intentar hacer algo por ellos mismos, pues la mayoría lo único que harán es copiar y pegar el código y hacerlo pasar por trabajo suyo.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, ciertamente soy un principiante que a penas cuenta con conocimientos de programación. La idea es ver cómo los demás me ayudan con ejemplos que yo propongo aquí para formarme una base. En cualquier caso, el objetivo a mediano plazo es ser autónomo, y por supuesto, también contribuir a los demás :D

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus comentarios, tendré muy en cuenta sus recomendaciones y consejos. De verdad, es un gusto aprender de esta gran comunidad :D